# How to free server side resources in RMI call?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

Our application is a client-server based application that I have converted from .NET remoting to ZMQ. We have two scenarios where a large image object is converted to a byte array in order to be serialized and sent to the client. In order to reduce memory issues (Large Object Heap) we have a pool of byte arrays that are used for this process, thus eliminating allocating and freeing them constantly.

The problem I have is that I do not know how to mark the byte arrays as "free" in the pool after returning the array in an RMI-like call.

```
public byte[] GetImageAreaGrey(int imageId)
    {
        var image = FindImageById(imageId);
        byte[] byteHolder = BytePool.GetFreeArray();
        ByteConverter.ConvertImageToBytes(image, byteHolder)
        return byteHolder ; // byteHolder will be serialized in the communications code using JSON.NET
        // How do I return byteHolder to the pool so that is available for future use?
    }
```

The application is written in C# with .NET 4.5 run time and we are trying to prevent fragmentation of the Large Object Heap.

edit: clarified that the raw byte[] is being returned.

Comment: Would it not be eligible for garbage collection after the RMI call returns?

Comment: It's not garbage collected...that's the whole point of having the pool of arrays. I will clarify that this is a C# .NET 4.5 application.

Comment: I clearly missed the part about a resource pool.

Comment: Use try/finally and return the byte array to the pool in the finally clause.

Comment: @darri - that won't work because the serialisation of the array to send it back to the caller happens after the method returns; if you did that you could randomly see another request starting to use the byte array and overwriting data before it is sent.

Comment: True, I didn't realize the actual byte array is being returned.

Comment: You can do that with WCF by returning a *Stream*, WCF will call its *Dispose* when it is done with your stream.

Comment: @EZI I do not have the option of using WCF, however your solution might not be limited to WCF, so it would be beneficial if you posted it anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Old answer: The pool has to keep track of which arrays are free, and which are used. You need separate collections for free and non-free arrays. This is a basic requirement for any pool, so I am not sure what kind of pool you are talking about.

New answer: after reading the comments, I understand the question better. You wish to return a byte array to the pool, but the byte array has been returned as a return value to a method which is invoked by external code. Is this the question? You cannot return it to the pool, since you don't know when the external code is finished with the byte array. You cannot use a pool.

In order to use a pool, you have to invert the control order. Your code has to call the external code with the byte array as an input parameter.

Comment: I am well aware that the pool is responsible for tracking the available and used arrays. The problem I have is that is certain circumstances, there is no obvious mechanism for informing the pool that the array is no longer being used and thus is available for re-use.

Comment: @DaveNay a pool has an "allocate" or "retrieve" method, and a "free" method. Without any way to reuse the object pooled, how can it be called a "pool"?

Comment: Yes, I know that. I am not asking how to create a pool of objects. Please fit the "Pool.Free(byte[])" call you have described into the scenario I have described. That is the point where i am having difficulty.

Comment: @DaveNay Your question was not clear to me (it is probably confusing to others as well). Perhaps my changes answer the question, or perhaps you could explain it better.